Why Checking Of getAction() member function of received Intent in onReceive(c : Context , i : Intent ) callback of BroadCastReceiver is Necessary
I've one manifest declared BroadCastReceiver , If i'm not checking the action of our received intent in onReceive() callback , i'm warned by lint compiler is not checking for action , is a security Issue .
When we've multiple events for a single receiver , it's logical to check for action . If i've single event receiver , why should I go for action check , moreover our definition of receiver is , it'll be called , when event of interest occurs.
Can anyone clarify me , what is the issue in case of single event receiver , why should we go for action check.
I'm expecting someone should clarify me , why checking of action in a single event receiver is necessary..
